# Emulate GameBoy Color's GameLink

Tags: emulation, gameboy

I'm currently developing a GameBoy Color Emulator for learning purposes. I also wanted to emulate the GameLink functionality (poké-fight ftw!), but I did not found any documentation, examples, references or source snippets on how to emulate the GameLink.

All GameBoy emulators I found on github didn't provide this functionality.

Programming Language doesn't matter, I'm just curious if there are resources on that topic out there.

Has anybody an idea on where to start with this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few links that might prove useful :

```
 http://image.diku.dk/projects/media/kirk.06.pdf
 http://www.hardwarebook.info/Game_Boy_Link
 http://fms.komkon.org/GameBoy/Tech/Hardware.html
```

The key appears to be to search G for gameboy gamelink protocol.

Apologies if you already know of them

Comment: Well this is very hardware specific. What I'm looking for is how the establishing and the destruction of the connection could be emulated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm willing to bet that, almost four years later, you no longer care but [the No$ documentation](http://bgb.bircd.org/pandocs.htm#serialdatatransferlinkcable) covers the serial port.

`$FF02` is a control port, `$FF01` is a data port.

The transmitter is expected to queue up a byte in `$FF01` then post a byte to `$FF02` indicating that: (i) a transfer should start; (ii) using an internally-generated clock.

The receiver should use `$FF02` to configure its port as expecting an internal clock. When it receives a byte it can inspect it via `$FF01`.

Sending or receiving a complete byte sets bit 3 of the interrupt register. So the receiver knows when it has received a byte by servicing that interrupt, and the transmitter similarly knows when it can send the next.